# Do you use a solution for all server related stuff (Git repositories, mail, database, web services) or many solutions?

Tags: java, hosting, xmpp, cloud-hosting

I would like to solve all my problems with domain

- place where I can store all my git repositories
- place where I can deploy my Java, (python, php) applications
- place where I have my jabber, mail, silc on my own domain

I don't have enough technical knowledge to run my own server, I would like to use somebody else solution but as cheap as possible. Is there cloud solution with these capabilities? Is there a trustful, cheap server provider? Or do you use many solutions like - gmail, github, aws/gae, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Finding everything you need in one place is fairly unlikely. I typically use [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/) for email and docs (they also support jabber), then use other services like [GitHub](https://github.com/) for Git hosting where needed. Deployment varies by project, but usually includes [AppEngine](http://appengine.google.com), [Heroku](http://heroku.com/), [SliceHost](http://www.slicehost.com/), or [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

I'd advise that you get familiar with a few services and try them out. If your experience is anything like mine, you will settle on services you like (and can afford).

Comment: This is an excellent piece of advice.  I'd throw in Rackspace Cloud products as a suggestion also.